# Use reduce instead of nested for loops?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops, reduce

I'm trying to print out the multiplication table using js. Is there a cleaner way to do this than with nested for loops? I was thinking of reduce as an alternative. Any onther ideas out there? ;)

```js
    let table = () => {
      let x, y, sum;
      let table = '';

      for (y = 10; y <= 20; y++) {
        for (x = 10; x <= 20; x++) {
          sum = x * y;
          table += `|${sum}   `;
        }
        table += '|\n';
      }
      result.innerText = table;
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Task 4</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="table()">
    <h2>Multiplication table</h2>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: SO is not for suggestions. Is there a problem with what you have? Reduce will be harder to read. You can start by creating an array of arrays, then trying to `reduce` it to a string.

Comment: Could it be done in one loop? yes using mods. Is it better? Up for discussion. lol

Comment: @LeoDog896 the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: a) use an actual HTML table b) use map+join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Since you have a nested for loop, you need two `reduce`s: a `reduce` per row and a `reduce` for the entire table :

```
range.map(x =>
        range.map(y => x * y).reduce((row, sum) => row + `|${sum}   `), '')
    .reduce((table, row) => table + row + '|\n', '');
```

**That being said, in your case you'd probably want to create an [HTML table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).**

#### Snippet

```js
let table = () => {
  const range = Array.from({length: 11}, (x, i) => i + 10);

  result.innerText = range.map(x =>
    range.map(y => x * y).reduce((row, sum) => row + `|${sum}   `), '')
  .reduce((table, row) => table + row + '|\n', '');
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Task 4</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="table()">
    <h2>Multiplication table</h2>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fixed it, we need a range of length 11, not 10 as you said.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create a 2D array and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to turn into a table formatted as a delimited string makes it easier to read than using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

What makes this easier to read and more flexible is that there is one step to generate your data model (2d array) and another to convert it to a string. Therefore, if you wanted to turn into an HTML table, it'd be really easy.

```js
const table = Array.from(
    {length: 11},
    (e, x) => Array.from(
        {length: 11},
        (e, y) => (x + 10) * (y + 10)
    )
);

const str = table.map((row) => `| ${row.join(" | ")} |`).join("\n");
console.log({
  table
});

result.innerText = str;

const html = `
<table><tbody>
${table.map(row => 
  `<tr>${row.map(el => 
    `<td>${el}</td>`).join("")
   }</tr>`).join("")
}
</tbody></table>`;

console.log({
  html
});
htmlTable.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="htmlTable"></div>
```